# Object Image not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have done the event handling method for Vue JS, Good news the button click event is working, but the bad news is that my image is not coming through.

What I do find interesting though is if I put the `innerHTML` in the HTML side of things the image does show.

Anything I am doing wrong?

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  baby: [

    {
      id: "botamon",
      name: "Botamon",
      stage: "Baby",
      type: "Data",
      digivolution: ["Koromon"],
      image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg"
    },

    {
      id: "poyomon",
      name: "Poyomon",
      stage: "Baby",
      type: "Data",
      digivolution: ["tokomon"],
      image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/86-poyomon.jpg"
    },

    {
      id: "punimon",
      name: "Punimon",
      stage: "Baby",
      type: "Data",
      digivolution: ["tsunomon"],
      image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/88-punimon.jpg"
    },

    {
      id: "yuramon",
      name: "Yuramon",
      stage: "Baby",
      type: "Data",
      digivolution: ["tanemon"],
      image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/123-yuramon.jpg"
    },
  ],

  methods: {
    blueEgg() {
      let container = document.querySelector(".container");
      container.innerHTML = `<div id="background">
            <div class="heading">
            <h1>In-training Stage</h1>
            <button class="close">X</button>
            </div>
            <div class="punimon-image">
            <img :src="baby[2].image" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
            `

    },
  },


})

app.mount('#app')
```

```css
.heading {
  display: flex;
}

.heading h1 {
  color: var(--green-color);
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0.5em 4em;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--green-color);
  border: none;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
}

.close {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.punimon-image {
  margin: 1.5em 1em;
}

.punimon-image img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="hero-image">
      <p class="display-5" id="choice">Which egg do you want?</p>
      <img src="../Images/hero-image.png" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="egg-choice">
      <img @click="blueEgg" src="/Images/Blue Egg - mobile.png" alt="Blue Egg" />
      <img src="/Images/Green Egg - mobile.png" alt="Green Egg" />
      <img src="/Images/Orange Egg - mobile.png" alt="Orange Egg" />
      <img src="/Images/Pink Egg - mobile.png" alt="Pink Egg" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between `https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg` and `/Images/Green Egg - mobile.png`? Btw, the second one looks like it's not a properly formatted/named path. Do not use `innerHTML`, you're in Vue realm, use the given API by the framework. In your `blueEgg` method, prefer mutating a state rather than doing DOM manipulations and injecting some markup. Why do you even need to inject it if you have it in the `baby` collection?

Comment: The only relation between them is that the ``../Images/Green Egg - mobile.png`` is the image that you click on, so that the next step appears

Comment: Still not clear how they interact together. Which step? How does it look? What about the rest of my comments?

Comment: I will look into the Vue API, I was still thinking vanilla JS, I added a screenshot to my question so you can see how it relates.
In short user clicks on blue egg image --> new section appears that contains missing image

Comment: Either use Vue or Vanilla JS, don't mix both since Vue is based on state and not DOM. How do you determine the missing image?